# How do I share an instance of a user control between classes?

Tags: c#, winforms

First of all, I don't understand a lot about this so I am sorry and please bear with me.

Let's say I have a user control within a form in the design screen. Is this an instance in itself? If so, how do I share this instance between classes easily?

I currently have a singleton class, which means I am making extra instances of each user control. However, when I call the user control instance through the singleton class, and `.Show()` or `.Visible = true`, then it does not appear. Only appears if I reference the name of the user control which is in the design properties window (which I guess is the first instance).

Also, do forms have their own instance when you load your application or do you need to instantiate? How do they work in terms of instantiation in comparison to user controls/controls?

If you need the code I will give it but I think it's more of a conceptual question I am asking. If you can provide sample code that would be wonderful.

Edit:

Singleton class:

```
class Single
{
    public Form1 Form { get; private set; }
    public Menu MenuForm { get; private set; }
    public RandomFacts RandomFactsForm { get; private set; }
    public QuizMenu QuizMenuForm { get; private set; }
    public AskHowManyQuestions AskHowManyQuestionsForm { get; private set; }
    public QuizUC QuizUserControl { get; private set; }
    public QuizSetupUC QuizSetupUserControl { get; private set; }

    private static readonly Form1 _form1 = new Form1();
    private static readonly Menu _menu = new Menu();
    private static readonly RandomFacts _randomFacts = new RandomFacts();
    private static readonly QuizMenu _quizMenu = new QuizMenu();
    private static readonly AskHowManyQuestions _askHowManyQuestions = new AskHowManyQuestions();
    private static readonly QuizUC _quizUC = new QuizUC();
    private static readonly QuizSetupUC _quizSetupUC = new QuizSetupUC();

    private static readonly Single _single = new Single();

    private Single()
    {
        Form = _form1;
        MenuForm = _menu;
        RandomFactsForm = _randomFacts;
        QuizMenuForm = _quizMenu;
        AskHowManyQuestionsForm = _askHowManyQuestions;
        QuizUserControl = _quizUC;
        QuizSetupUserControl = _quizSetupUC;
    }

    public static Single GetSingle()
    {
        return _single;
    }
}
```

Attempting to load a user control from the form in which it will be displayed (doesn't work):

```
private QuizSetupUC QuizSetupCon; // in scope of class

QuizSetupCon = Single.GetSingle().QuizSetupUserControl;
QuizSetupCon.Show();
QuizSetupCon.Location = new Point(40, 10);
```

But this works (the name of the user control in the form design):

```
quizSetupUC1.Show();
```

Comment: Everything in C# is a class. Forms too. And Their instances get created when the application runs. Notice `new Form1` in `Program.cs` ? What you are asking is very broad and does not explain what concept you not clear off. You need to read about concepts if you don't have them clear and share relevant code here if you are looking for an answer of a specific issue you are facing.

Comment: If you define the class as singleton so what is your problem?

Comment: @PouriaAnsari if I try to call the instance of the user control I create in singleton, it won't show. But if I call the instance created when the application is run then it will show. But I am trying to share the instance between classes.

Comment: You can show a control, just in case it's hosted on a top-level window.

Comment: @itzgeez - This code is a bad idea. A singleton like this will cause you no end of bugs and issues.

Comment: The instance that you try to show is different from the instance which is hosted on the form. The control cannot be visible without a parent.